# MySQL: How to update a row in the order of First In?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I was to provide users with the status of their past works. So in the table, I maintain `ID, Name, Work, completed` So the first three columns are filled before the works are completed and the last column is updated when the works are done.

For instance, when the process is given I make a row to the table as

```
ID      Name       work       completed
1       ABC         10           NULL
```

So once the work is completed, say we were able to complete only 8 out of 10 at the end. so I want to update this row with completed is updated with 8 than Null.

But the thing is sometimes the user gives 2 or more separate works at the same time. so the initial entry will be

```
ID      Name       work       completed
1       ABC         10           8
2       ABC         30           NULL
3       ABC         17           NULL
```

In the above case the `ID 1` is a past job and nothing is to be done. But when `ID 2` is done I want to update it, but I dont have the ID in my hand I want to do `WHERE name = "ABC" and completed = NULL` But if I do this both the ID 2 and 3 will be updated. How can I update it correctly? as first updatation should go to ID 2 and second updation entry should affect only ID 3?

I'm using python MYSQL connector and not well versed with MySQL but I do know basics. So if you could explain the query a bit it will be highly appreciated.

Comment: `but I dont have the ID in my hand`  That is a bad design of your application ! You must know somehow which job is getting completed. What if ABC completes the work 17 out of 17 first then finishes 30 ?

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible check if a `field = NULL` you need to use the `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` tests.

e.g.

```
WHERE name = "ABC" and completed IS NULL
```

Comment: Is this an answer to his query ?